# How to click ElementByTagName img with source in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I want click element is `<img src="">`, like this:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="close">
        <img src="images/close.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

in JavaScript.

I usually click by: `document.getElementById().click();`

Comment: Do you want to click the element based on its source being `"images/close.png"`, or do you want to click all the `img` elements on the page?

Comment: I only want click element `<img src="images/close.png">`.

Comment: Since *getElementsByTagName* returns a NodeList, you'll need to specify which one, e.g. : `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].click()` to click the first one. Or you can use *document.images* to save some typing: `document.images[0].click()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByTagName("img")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) will return a `HTMLCollection` of the image elements. You will want to loop through them and check if the source is the value you want, then use `.click` on that image:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
    if(imgs[i].src == "images/close.png") imgs[i].click();
}
```

Note that when checking the source you will want to check the full path, rather than the relative one.

Comment: If I want click second span(`<span></span>`) in this case: `<div class="mini-ott">
 <span class="ott-name"></span>
 <span></span>
</div>`. You have any method to do this?

Comment: @VănLộc Something like `document.getElementsByClassName("ott-name")[0].click()` would work. To click all of the with that class then you would use a for loop similar to the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

There are two images. Only the one with a given src has the onclick property.

```js
var imgArr = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0, len = imgArr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  if (imgArr[i].src === 'http://yeoman.io/static/yeoman-character-sticker.51cef7e007.png') {
    imgArr[i].onclick = function() {
      alert('I am clicked');
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="close">
    <img src="http://yeoman.io/static/yeoman-character-sticker.51cef7e007.png">
    <img src="http://yeoman.io/static/illustration-home-inverted.91b07808be.png">
  </div>
</div>
```